# How to pass a value to two actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have three actions that I have a value in the first action, I pass this value to the second action. I want to use this amount in the third action, is there a solution?

First Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser(LoginViewModel viewModel)
{          
    string code = await _user.SendActiveCodeForUser(viewModel);
    TempData["Mobile"] = viewModel.Mobile;
    return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Activate") });       
}
```

Second Action:

```
public IActionResult Activate()
{
    ViewBag.Mobile = TempData["Mobile"].ToString();           
    return View();           
}
```

Third Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendActiveCode()
{
    string code = await _user.SendActiveCodeAgain(ViewData["Mobile"].ToString());
    return Json(0);
}
```

Comment: What kinds of values are you wanting to pass? Entire complex object-graphs (i.e. object instances) or just simple scalars (`string`, `int`, etc)?

Comment: @Dai string value

Comment: A single `string` value? How long are these values?

Comment: @Dai just a mobile number

Comment: You can pass it as an querystring parameter then, which you can also make optional, like so: `public IActionResult Activate( [FromQuery] String? mobilePhoneNumber = null )` - when generating URLs with `IUrlHelper` specify `mobilePhoneNumber` in your `RouteValueDictionary` _or_ anonymous-type object, e.g. `Url.Action( action: nameof(HomeController.Activate), controller: "Home", routeValues: new { mobilePhoneNumber = "425-111-1234" } )`

Comment: You can just call an action like any other method. They're just public methods, so actions can call each other. I don't think you mean you want the separate request and responses. Because that would require more handing.

Comment: @JHBonarius I think a session is a good solution

Comment: What "session" are you talking about. Back to this question: likely not all of these methods should be actions at all... if nothing is checking the response,  it should response not give one.

Answer (score 0):

I used the session according to the link address below, I think it is a good solution

[How To Use Sessions In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Using Session-state makes it much more difficult for applications to scale horizontally (e.g. web-farm scenarios) because it means you can't use stateless load-balancing - at least not without an expensive or complicated shared session-state persistence system.